# Can I develop Lego Mindstorms in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, lego-mindstorms

Is there a Java SDK for Lego Mindstorms? Can I compile Scala code to JAR and run it in Lego Mindstorms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely no, but difficult to say. Mindstorm JVMs aren't complete JVMs, though they're not bad.

That said:

Even assuming all the classes you needed were available, Scala "lets" you use large quantities of memory before you realize what's happening. It's not *certain*–you can control what parts of Scala you use. Restricting yourself eliminates some of Scala's advantages, though.

My approach would be to run a server (or client) on the bot and use Scala on a real machine to control the bot over wireless. Obviously this has its own set of disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's not valid anymore, but you can develop in Scala for Mindstorms EV3, here is an example:
https://github.com/t3hnar/ev3.helloworld

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Lego Mindstorms (never seen it), but generally, yes. You can compile your scala code to JAR, add scala-library.jar, and run it just like normal Java program.

If your program accepts only one jar, you can combine your JAR with scala-library.jar and create a single file.

Comment: My intuition was the same, but as the LeJOS (Java for Lego Mindstorms) uses an own compiler called nxjc I am not so sure about this.